# SSIS Job scheduler fine, but running fail in MSDB integration Services

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

SSIS package running fail in MSDB integration Services, but it running fine ib vs and job scheduler.

Error is : **dts_e_cannotacquireconnectionfromconnectionmanager. AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "XXX failed with error code 0xC0202009".
It is happend when the pachage whant to connect to oracle db*

Are there any ways to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you tried running the package with 32 bits instead of 64 bits..

Comment: yes. This package is running with 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

If your connection manager is parametrized, make sure you are using the parameters when testing in Visual Studio. Some connection managers are finicky that way.